# How do I get the current PathName with a custom domain name in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm trying to generate invitations links to my application.

The link must be the exact domain name the user is navigating which is  http://www.mycompany.com.br/ but when I try this:

```cs
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme+"://"+HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host+"/SignUp/"
```

It returns this: http://mycompany.azurewebsites.net/SignUp/
Instead of the custom DNS name: http://www.mycompany.com.br/SignUp/

Comment: Have you tried HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri

Comment: Tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost`? Not sure though as it should actually be the same as `Host` in this case.

Comment: @EdneyHolder yes, it does return the custom name but it also returns the API/ path

Comment: @bolkay It worked but did not include the https, then I tried adding HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme+"://"+, then it returned the wrong value, very strange.

Comment: @ArthurPaiva you should check the request's Host header, not the URl's. A single site can serve multiple domains through host headers. A browser sends the domain in the HOST header, not as part of the URL. That header will be passed by firewalls and routers all the way to the web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code to get `http://www.mycompany.com.br/`

```
string strPathAndQuery = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
string strUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(strPathAndQuery, "/");
```